# Google maps api gm_bindings_ undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am making a list of the markers that I have under the map, and when a user clicks it should display that marker but it doesn't. I get a console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'gm_bindings_' of undefined

Now I'm stuck and turning to you for help.

Some code:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
map.addMarkers(allMarkers);
jQuery(document).on('click','.address',function(){
        marker = allMarkers[this.id];
        infowindow.open(map, marker); //The error occurs on this line.
});
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5nxbd7o2/1/

Look in the console to see the error.

Comment: 1. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be helpful as well) 2. How do we generate the error?

Comment: Just click on any of the addresses, I am logging the marker object also.

Comment: geocodezip I added the fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are using gmaps3, not the Google Maps Javascript API v3 directly.  Your map variable is a [GMap](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/) object, not a google.maps.Map object.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f95wkmz5/13/)

Change this:

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.address',function(){
    marker = allMarkers[this.id];
    console.log(marker);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

To:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.address', function () {
    marker = allMarkers[this.id];
    console.log(marker);
    marker.infoWindow.open(map.map, marker);
    // will center the map on the marker
    map.map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

Notice I also modified the code to open the infowindow.

If you want to uncluster the marker, you will need to add code to zoom in as well:

```
map.map.setZoom(20);
```

[fiddle that does that](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/f95wkmz5/14/)

Comment: Any idea how to close all other windows?

Comment: That is the way the library you are using works.  I don't use third party libraries all that much, I would expect it would have some option to do that, perhaps [hideInfoWindows](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-hideInfoWindows)